# Position image in top right corner of a web page

Tags: html, css

I would like to put some image to the top and right of the text... I made an example in Photoshop so you may see what I had in mind....

[Image example](http://prntscr.com/8b9m80)

I am using a WordPress theme, and I cannot figure out how to place this image to the top right corner... yes, I did search the google but I didnt find any suitable solution.

I tried as a background image of a div, but the image cannot go beyond the confines of a div...

I tried putting img tag, but it pushes the text to the left ... but I need the text to go over the image to create the desired effect

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does your current code and output look like? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 80%;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4p0bLurz/)

Comment: looks good, need to incorporate it... will let you know.. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

add in css

```
body{
background-image:url("your image path");
background-position: right top;
background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/swaranan/q0p7t7vh/)

Comment: Do you have any class for the content section??if have then make this background white;

Comment: thank you Swaranan, the thing is, this is wordpress theme, with so many divs and rows and clearfixes...

Comment: can u provide me the link so i can tell you the actual class of the div.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.example {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <p>Text example</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add class to the image i.e 
         .toprightcorner{ position:absolute; top:0; right:0; }
after applying the css . Hope it works out. If n't let me know.

Comment: this flawed as it depends on other things to work, also, that's not a nice class name

Comment: well it works, thanks suresh... the only glitch is when I try to resize the window, the image remains a bit hidden to the right...

Comment: can you share me the page how it looks after resize..??

Comment: Other things in the sense what?? I agree class name is bit long i can reduce it,  i jst added keywords of question and mentioned like that.. @ToniLeigh

Comment: it's not the length of the class name that is wrong (short is less important than full of the needed meaning) - it's bad because it mentions the position of the image, what happens if the image moves to the left and you end up with a class called 'top right' which puts the image in the top left?

Comment: position absolute will only work if the parent is positioned to something other than static, also, it will only go to the top and right of the next element up the DOM tree that is has it's position set to something other than static, which you cannot be 100% sure will be the screen given future maintenance and development requirements that are as yet unknown - both these things make the above solution a bit brittle, especially when compared to a background image on something like the container.

Comment: Thnx for d information.I thought class name need to b meaningful, usually i follow a scenario like class name need to represent purpose of class. one more thing is i considered the image as logout image and given the class. if it is background image i wnt use that class i may prefer some other way.

Comment: @suresh - the best class names are meaningful, but in a way that doesn't describe the style and leaves them page context free, while conveying enough meaning to be unambiguous and easy to understand: for example - `.box-highlighted` is better than `.login-box` or `.blue-box` - it conveys all the necessary meaning for the programmer without being too tightly tied to it's current styling or it's usage on the page